# hasClass jQuery isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a navigation system where left and right arrows expand LIs.

```
<a href="#" class="icon-arrow-left active"></a>
     <ul>
        <li class="contracted"><a href="#">1</a></li>
        <li class="expanded"><a href="#">2</a></li>
        <li class="activeLesson"><a href="#">3</a></li>
        <li class="expanded"><a href="#">4</a></li>
        <li class="contracted"><a href="#">5</a></li>
    </ul>
<a href="#" class="icon icon-arrow-right active"></a>
```

When fist li is 'expanded' 'icon-arrow-left' should be 'inactive' and when last li is 'expanded' 'icon icon-arrow-right' should be inactive.

I tried to use this but not working

```
 if ($('li:first-child').hasClass('activeLesson')) {
        $('.icon-arrow-left').attr('class','inactive')
        }
```

Here is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xhP74/)

Comment: Prepare a fiddle explaining your question

Comment: You're totally wiping out all the classes on `.icon-arrow-left`. That isn't what you want, is it?

Comment: why so many downvotes? question is properly asked. Shouldnt be a problem to be a newbie

Comment: I was also scared why downvoted so much, but remembered this is SO.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `attr('class','inactive')`, this will totally wipe out all the classes that you have.

> You should use [toggle class method](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

```
if ($('li:first-child').hasClass('expanded')) {
        $('.icon-arrow-left').toggleClass('active inactive');
}
```

If the class has active then it use inactive and if the class has inactive then it use active class.

Comment: Hi! Thanks you. 
But this does not work. I've updated my question with jsFiddle link to make it more sense. Please check that.

Comment: you're still using attr method. just copy my code and see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

use `addClass("active")` / `removeClass("inactive")` . If you set it with `.attr` , you erase all the classes.